# [Python IDE]Call a function defined in the .py file in console

Tags: python, eclipse, pycharm, pydev, spyder

Is it possible to configure PyDev-in-Eclipse or PyCharm in order to be able to call a function defined in the editing .py file in the console ?

For example, in the editor, there is a *test.py* open:

```
def add(x, y):
    return x+y
```

Then in the console:

```
>> add(3,4)
```

I noticed that it is possible in Spyder. However, by default, in PyCharm and PyDev, the console will return "No name 'add' defined" error.
My question is: is it possible to achieve this interaction between editor and console in PyCharm or PyDev ?

All answers and suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Not an answer but a suggestion. If you debug the program in pycharm you can view the output of functions by clicking the evaluate expressions button or alt+F8. Alternatively you can copy past the function into the console and then you should be able to call it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to give the Python console in PyCharm access to the variable space of a script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26354977/how-to-give-the-python-console-in-pycharm-access-to-the-variable-space-of-a-scri)

Comment: This is not the case for Spyder, unless you're using a very old version of it (2.2.x or 2.1.x). And in that case, this was only true because you defined a function called `add` (which is part of Numpy). If you call your function `add_foo` then you'll see the same error as in PyDev and PyCharm.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba，Yes, you're right ! Thank you ! I am sorry for this stupid question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In any IDE to my knowledge, if you are running from the same directory as the file, it should be as simple as

```
import test

test.add(3,4)
```

or

```
from test import add

add(3,4)
```

What is your ultimate goal though? python packaging is a bit more complex if you are looking to distribute or use elsewhere in your code.

see - https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html

Answer (score 1):

In PyDev, use `Ctrl+Alt+Enter` to make a runfile of the current editor in the console (if no text is selected), so that its symbols are available for further experimentation (and it may also be used to open a console if there's no open console).

See: http://www.pydev.org/manual_adv_interactive_console.html for more details on how to properly use the interactive console in PyDev.