# Why does my PyCharm console not run my function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nameerror

[image]

```
def is_table(tab):
   if len(tab) != 3:
      return False
   valid = (-1, 0, 1)
   for a in range(0, 3):
      if len(tab[a]) != 3:
         return False
      for b in range(0, 3):
         if tab[a][b] not in valid:
            return False
   return True
```

When I try to run `is_table(((0,0,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0)))` on console, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'is_table' is not defined
```

Can anyone explain why? My function is clearly defined, but it still doesn't run on console.

Answer (score 1):

The python console dont know about your files functions. First, edit your file name, removing any space, e.g., *jogo_do_galo.py* (or another name, like *jogo_do_mengao*).

Open the python console, and try:

```
>>> from jogo_do_galo import *
>>> tab = ((True, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0))
>>> eh_tabuleiro(tab)
```

This will work.

Answer (score 0):

Did you define the function inside the console, or in a separate file?

If you defined the function in a separate file, you'll need to run the file before the function will be recognized by the console.

Comment: I defined it in a separate file. I have run the file multiple times, and it still does not recognize it. Any other guesses? Maybe I could upload a print screen of my code or something

Comment: @sousa16 Did you make sure that the console indicated that a file has been run?

Comment: how would I do that? I'm relatively new to coding, sorry.

Comment: from [your file name] import *

Comment: @sousa16 A screenshot would help.

Comment: I double clicked the file and pressed run

Comment: Just uploaded the screenshot.

Comment: and how could I fix this?

Comment: @sousa16 Run `python yourfile.py` in the console.

Comment: it returns invalid syntax because of the space

Comment: @sousa16 Use double quotes around your filename: `python "yourfile.py"`.

Comment: still returns invalid syntax. I am running this on pycharm console, is that correct? Just checking to see if maybe I should run it on Terminal. But I'm pretty sure I should be able to run what I was trying to run on console

Comment: @sousa16 I found [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26357907/13552470) here.

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer. Right-clicked on file name, settings, run on console.