# Pycharm variable list

Tags: python, variables, ide, pycharm

I am very new to Python and trying out different IDEs. Pycharm seems to be highly recommended and I like the interface, but I can't for the life of my find out how to get a list of variables. I have searched Google and found a similar question here on StackOverflow ([Is there a Variable Explorer for PyCharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23941580/is-there-a-variable-explorer-for-pycharm)) however I cannot reproduce the suggested results.

I believe I should run the code in the debugger and then there should be a list of variables but when I do that under Frames is says "Frames are not available" and under Variables "Frame is not available". I would post a screenshot but I don't have enough reputation to do so yet.

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: You have to add a break point by double clicking on the margin of the line of code of interest.

Comment: See https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/debug-tool-window.html and the linked https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/starting-the-debugger-session.html

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you. It's not as nice looking at R or Matlab, which I've worked with a lot, but it shows the vars and that's what I need.

Comment: The answer is in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23941580/is-there-a-variable-explorer-for-pycharm#

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a Variable Explorer for PyCharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23941580/is-there-a-variable-explorer-for-pycharm)