# How to make edited dataframe show in Pycharm

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pycharm

Here's my file( edited with data included.)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")

print(df)
```

Here's the result. This dataframe comes up on Pycharm when I print it.

```
Date      Campaign
3/24/20   GA Shoes Search Campaign
3/24/20   GA Shoes Display Campaign
3/24/20   GA Bag Search Campaign
3/24/20   GA Bag Display Campaign
3/24/20   IG Shoes Campaign
3/24/20   IG Bag Campaign
3/24/20   FB Shoes Campaign
3/24/20   FB Bag Campaign
3/24/20   Email Campaign
```

But then when I created a function to edit my dataframe, it wouldn't come up anymore

```
def edit():
    new = df.loc[df.Campaign.str.startswith("GA")]
    return new
print(edit())
```

I want this to come up as a dataframe:

```
Date      Campaign
3/24/20   GA Shoes Search Campaign
3/24/20   GA Shoes Display Campaign
3/24/20   GA Bag Search Campaign
3/24/20   GA Bag Display Campaign
```

I tried debugger but only the original df comes up with "View as DataFrame," my new and edited dataframe won't show up. How do i make my edited dataframe show on Pycharm?

Comment: `.str` is method you can use only on `pd.series`. What do you want to do exactly ? Show us a sample of your df and the result you expect

Comment: @Pi-R it returned a series with boolean type. The result i want is the edited dataframe

Comment: share the data so we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: @MaximKogan post edited

Comment: In Jupyter Notebook your code works fine.

Comment: @Pi-R I'm using Pycharm. I want the edited dataframe to show for me to check whether the result the code produced is what I really want. But in Pycharm the edited dataframe won't come up

Comment: check this post 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23941580/is-there-a-variable-explorer-for-pycharm#:~:text=Click%20the%20debug%20button%20or,view%20it%20as%20a%20dataframe.