# Module not found when debugging

Tags: python, pycharm

I am running a Python client using PyCharm. If I just run it, PyCharm simply calls:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe E:/faf/client/src
```

and everything is fine.

These are my settings:

[image]

If I want to debug it, PyCharm calls:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 5.0.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py" --multiproc --qt-support --client 127.0.0.1 --port 52948 --file E:/faf/client/src
```

and the result is that the modules which are in fact *there* cannot be included

```
pydev debugger: process 5092 is connecting

Connected to pydev debugger (build 143.1184)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 5.0.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 2407, in <module>
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 5.0.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1798, in run
    launch(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "E:/faf/client/src\__main__.py", line 29, in <module>
    import config
ImportError: No module named config
```

What do I have to do to be able to debug this thing?

Comment: Did you try specifying working directory with src? What is config? Is it file in same directory?

Comment: @Andrey Yeah, that was the problem indeed. I think it's strange that I have to do that because after doing so, nothing really obvious  changed in the run configuration O_o Despite having two close-votes I'll not delete my answer because how should one know that?

Comment: I guess that python.exe uses the folder of py file as working directory, while "pydevd.py" sets working directory somehow and it is not visible from command line

Comment: @Andrey Yes, and unfortunately it's not obvious ^^ But thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to click on the `src` directory and add it as source folder (`Mark Directory As -> Source Root`). No apparent thing changed like e.g. the way the python command got called.

So if you have a similar looking problem try to do the same.

Comment: Didn't work with for `google-auth 1.6.1 (used with import google.auth)`, still the same error in `PyCharm 2018.3 Professional`

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue for myself by adding an **init**.py in the folder of the module I was trying to import.