# Debug Robot Framework tests from Pycharm

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm, robotframework

I'm writing tests on robot Framework and use some python functions with it.
So I have the **start.sh** shell script that runs my testcases. But in my tests I use python functions, that was written by myself and I want to debug it and sometimes see the variables. How can I do it in PyCharm?
I tried to add shell script in debug configuration, but it didn't help. Also I tried to run start shell script from python script, but I also couldn't get to breakpoints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you using this start.sh?  If you're using PyCharm, you can run your test cases via it and set breakpoints in whatever functions you want.  Just setup a configuration for it

I just call run.py for the script:
    C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\robot\run.py

Script params:
    --monitorcolors ansi --loglevel DEBUG --outputdir TestResults --exclude "Exclude_me" TestSuite

Then ensure you have your python interpreter set correctly and your working directory.

This question may also help - [HOW TO use Pycharm to debug python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10240018/how-to-use-pycharm-to-debug-python-script?rq=1)

Comment: I should add those arguments are NOT specfic to what you need, they're just an example.

Comment: @KseniyaBuraya Question title is not the same as the question details. As according to your question title, you want to debug test cases itself and not the python libraries.

Comment: Nothing was mentioned for libraries, test cases will largely be some english language which is actually a wrapper for underlying python functions.  The question was clear enough after reading, why the downvotes for my answer which clearly helped!?

Comment: @AhmedWas, PyCharm does not allow debugging Robot scripts - only running them as "an external tool". Ant the latter is so user-unfriendly that it's not worth the effort. Besides, using Python-based keywords provides much cleaner test script that using Robot keywords - which are too generic (and not too convenient to use, especially for SW professionals). So your comment - based solely on the virtue of the title, and not the essence of the question - is not helpful. And down-vote is unjustified. I used the same technique - works as (Py)charm :)