# Unable to import package: Issues with InputHookManager

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I have now spent the last hour or so trying to fix this issue but failed. I have read several related questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37527761/debugging-python-code-in-pycharm), GitHub issues such as [this](https://github.com/HydraChain/hydrachain/issues/47) but can't find how to best solve this issue.

**Steps leading to the error**

1. `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`

Error message:

> AttributeError: 'InputHookManager' object has no attribute '_stdin_file'

**EDIT**

1. Importing as follows throws the same error(please see details of my system and failed attempts below):

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
```

2. **It works at the Terminal**

**Failed attempts**

I then opened the file that defines InputHookManager and noticed that it had something to do with `ipython` and `pydev` so I reinstalled `ipython` but that didn't solve the issue.

I also tried reinstalling `matplotlib` to no avail. The same error happens with `seaborn` presumably because they both need to use gtk3.

**More details about the system**

```
python 3.6
pycharm community 2019.2.1
Ubuntu 18.04.3
matplotlib 3.1.1
```

Comment: does it work outside of pycharm? just open a python interpreter in the console and try that same import.

Comment: It works if I just use the Terminal.

Answer (score 6):

If IPython didn't work, try the following. PyCharm seems unhappy with the interactive mode in Linux.

```py
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Comment: This works for me. I am also on Ubuntu with pycharm.

Answer (score 2):

I have exactly the same problem. I am on Ubuntu 18.04 using PyCharm 2020.2. Take a look at:["UserWarning: Matplotlib is currently using agg, which is a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure." when plotting figure with pyplot on Pycharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56656777/userwarning-matplotlib-is-currently-using-agg-which-is-a-non-gui-backend-so)

`sudo apt-get install python3-tk`
solves the problem

20200902 update: unfortunately I see this error again. This seems to fix:

```
import matplotlib 
matplotlib.use('TkAgg') 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

plt.show() now can show plots

Answer (score 1):

try this one it worked for me:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
```

Comment: I already tried it. It doesn't work. I'm thinking of using a different IDE for now until I figure out how to solve this. I've wasted enough time already.

Answer (score 1):

After wasting a lot of time and trying out different IDEs,  I finally solved it as follows:

**Assumptions:**

1. You're using a Linux distro(I was using Ubuntu 18.04.3)

Now uninstall `ipython` with the default `pip` as follows:

```
sudo python -m pip uninstall ipython
```

It will throw an error if `ipython` doesn't exist(good).

Now, install `ipython`:

```
sudo python -m pip install ipython
```

My understanding is that PyCharm is somehow using the default `matplotlib`(python 2.7) instead of the project specific interpreter package(`matplotlib` from python 3.6 here). You could therefore possibly solve this by resolving that conflict.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem, the only solution worked for me is to install PyQt5 `pip3 install PyQt5`, after the installation, it works like a charm again.